# CURL: empty file in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, curl

If i run this command in linux command line manually it works, and EDIT.3126026369 is not empty

```
curl "http://somesite.com/admin.php?mod=editnews&action=editnews&id=14058" -s -L -b cookie.ck -c cookie.ck > EDIT.3126026369
```

in bash:

```
curl \"$EDIT\" -s -L -b $COOKIE -c $COOKIE > EDIT.$TEMP
```

but in a bash script it generate an empty file. what am missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the quotes when defining your $EDIT variable:

```
EDIT="http://somesite.com/admin.php?mod=editnews&action=editnews&id=14058"
```

Then lose the escaped quotes on the curl command:

```
curl $EDIT -s -L -b $COOKIE -c $COOKIE > EDIT.$TEMP
```

Seems to work fine for me this way, how about you?

Comment: To clarify, if you enter those 2 commands I highlighted into a bash prompt it doesn't work ? (well, COOKIE and TEMP would need to be defined too I suppose... but you get where I'm going, trying to figure out how what you're doing is different than me...)

Comment: no if i run curl http://somesite.com/admin.php?mod=editnews&action=editnews&id=14058 -s -L -b $COOKIE -c $COOKIE > EDIT.$TEMP it's ignoring everything after the ampersand [1]+  Done                    curl http://somesite/admin.php?mod=editnews

Comment: if i run curl "http://somesite.com/admin.php?mod=editnews&action=editnews&id=14058"
 -s -L -b $COOKIE -c $COOKIE > EDIT.$TEMP it works...

Comment: basically i need quotes for the ampersand in my link, but adding quotes in bash script doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

What's in your `$EDIT` variable, and do you need to quote it like that? If it's your URL, I would simply expect you to write

```
curl $EDIT ....
```

If you run your bash script with a `-x` option, it'll show you each line that it executes. That's a very useful debugging technique.

Comment: the url link...the first command is an actual output from echo "curl \"$EDIT\" -s -L -b $COOKIE -c $COOKIE > EDIT.$TEMP"
and i added quote because it contains ampersand in the link